# Can I disable the refactor preview in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

When renaming a variable using Eclipse, I always get a popup dialog showing me a preview of the refactoring.  Is there some way I can disable this popup dialog?  In other words, I want to place the cursor over a variable name, press alt+shift+r, edit the variable name, press enter, and have the renaming take place without ever seeing the preview.  Is there some preference or setting for this?

I"m using Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)

**UPDATE**:

To test this, I did the following.  I created a new Java Project and added the following class to the package.

```
public class TestRename{
    private int var;
}
```

This is the only code in the project and still when I try to rename `var` I get a preview dialog in which I have to click "OK" to make the change.  I'm pretty sure this wasn't the default behavior in Eclipse, but I must have edited the defaults somehow.  I just don't know what I did or how to reset the preview behavior of the refactor.

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this. Questions like that prove that Eclipse is far from a really good IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a preference under "Java" for this called "Rename in editor without dialog". If this is not selected, the rename dialog will show up every time.

[image]

Comment: I have it unchecked and it still prompts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Helios, a dialog only appears when you are potentially creating a name conflict or refactoring code that has compile errors.